# SQL: How to generate a unique value for a Primary Key

Tags: mysql, sql, datatable, primary-key

as the title states. I do have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE exampleTable(
    ID int NOT NULL,
    Text varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

By inserting Values:

```
INSERT INTO exampleTable (ID, Text)
VALUES (123, 'Hello World');
```

Sometimes a value can be added for a Primary Key, which is already in the Table, thereby will give you an `Error`.

**Questions**:

1. By which approach can we ensure that the value of a choosen Primary Key is always unique?
2. How to generate a Primary Key value, that is always going to be unique.

**For 2. Question**, possible approach:

```
//Check if the new Value is already in the Table by
//Iterating and comparing through all the Primary Key Values.
```

Comment: You want [`auto_increment`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? I can't think of another reason to not use autoincrement.

Comment: Hey, the table wasn't set with auto_increment. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first answer is simple

1. The PRIMARY KEY Constraint guarantee that the values are UNIQUE and you get an [error](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/constraint-primary-key.html) if not
2. is more complicated, you can try to get the max(id) and then increase it either in source code or in  a BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER, but in heavy duty servers you can get still errors anyway, that is why we use auto_increment or uuids

Comment: Thank you, i am going to try the max(id) out.

Answer (score 0):

If you sent a primary key constrains, it only allow unique value.
You can enable Auto-increment/IsIDentity column true.

---

An alternate way is change the type of id to uniqueidentifier and insert Guid manually.
That would always unique. 
But not recommended

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to get a unique value for a primary key without using auto-increment? One answer: When there's a distributed application with multiple people trying to generate keys that are unique across all instances **AND** network latency prohibits accessing a central server for a key **AND** it's permissible to have a small "collision" rate.

Comments about this answer:

1. It's cumbersome and might take too much computer time.
2. It does not 100% guarantee unique keys -- just very, very close.
3. It's possible to get an arbitrary confidence factor that the generated key is unique by generating a longer key (change Result_Length to a larger number.
4. I have tested this algorithm on 8-letter keys and find less than 1 collision per 1,000,000 keys generated.

The solution expressed in VBA code:

```
Public Function fnGenerateAlmostUniqueKey as String
    ' Function to return almost-guaranteed-unique key value
    ' Increasing Result_Length decreases the probability of a collision
    ' Function returns a string like "AF4r9U7Y"
    Const Result_Length as long = 8   ' Adjust as needed
    Const Alpha as string = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
    Dim idx as long
    Dim Result as string
    Dim s as string        ' Intermediate value
    Randomize(Now())       ' Prevents everyone from using the same RND sequence
    For idx = 1 To Result_Length
        s = Mid(Alpha, Int(1 + Rnd() * 60), 1)
        Result = Result & s
    Next idx
    fnGenerateAlmostUniqueKey = Result
End Function
```